# CSS Not Loaded after Deployed in App Service ASP Net Core Razor Page Identiy Server 4

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor, azure-web-app-service, blazor

My CSS is working normally when I debug my app. After I publish it to my APP Service my CSS is not loaded. I already restart my app service but my login page from the Identity Server is back to normal. It's very strange because in debug it works properly

Comment: Any browser console messages about missing style sheets?

Comment: oh thank god, I already figured it out, because the wwwroot in app service is not updated, I end up changing my style to inline CSS. I still wonder why my CSS is not in wwrwoot in app service

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang In order to help people who may have the same problem as you, can you share your answer or step by step answer?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang I found when I scaffolded some of the Identity pages. The process placed _Layout.cshtml in the pages/shared folder. However it refers to a style sheet in the Identity area. I changed that line to <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />